# Void pointer void type cast function call?

Tags: pointers, memory, void, portable-executable, entry-point

Ok this is odd. It's the first time I've seen such a line of code.
Basically this calls the entry point into an application once you've specified an offset (address) from a program's PE header.

As you can tell - I've been playing lately with writing my own PE loader. I'm still a beginner and attempting to understand the structure - but what exactly is that function call mean?

**((void(*)(void))EntryPoint)();**

```
//where 0x4484502 is gotten from:

PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt_header;
DWORD EntryPoint = nt_header->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + nt_header->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;

((void(*)(void))0x4484502)();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
((void(*)(void))0x4484502)();
```

Casts the integer 0x4484502 to a point to a function (starting at that address) that has void parameters and returns void. Once cast, the function pointer is called.

EDIT:
Just re-read the question.... replace 0x4484502 with `EntryPoint` does exactly the same thing... the variable `EntryPoint` is cast as a pointer to a function that has void params and returns void. Pointer then used to call function.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for explaining. I was confused because I've never seen void(*) before. Google wasn't resourceful either - it just gave me void pointers (voidSTAR).

Comment: Glad it helped :) In general a function pointer is declared as

`return-type (*ptr_name)(..parameters);`

For example `int (*f)(int, short)` is a pointer, `f`, to a function that returns an int and accepts two parameters, an int and a short.

Answer (score 0):

notation

```
(some_type)something
```

it is C-style cast. It is equal to a sequence of C++ casts, but without `dynamic_cast` so it is dangerous - it allows you to cast a pointer to private base to a pointer to derived class not only in derived class functions.

here we have

```
(void(*)(void))0x4484502
```

it means that 0x4484502 is casted to a **pointer to a function** that takes void and returns void.

the notation `func_ptr()`

means call the function pointed to by `func_ptr`.

---

you can always check such strange declarations on [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/)